# How do I make Neo4J continue after conditional create

Tags: neo4j, cypher

After having created a collection of nodes, some of the nodes should also have a relation attached based on a condition. In the example below the condition is simulated with `WHERE n.number > 3` and the nodes are simple numbers:

```
WITH [2, 3, 4] as numbers
UNWIND numbers AS num
CREATE(n:Number {number: num})
WITH collect(n) AS nodes
UNWIND nodes AS n
WITH nodes, n WHERE n.number > 3
CREATE (n)-[:IM_SPECIAL]->(n)
RETURN nodes
```

Which returns:

```
╒════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"nodes"                                 │
╞════════════════════════════════════════╡
│[{"number":2},{"number":3},{"number":4}]│
└────────────────────────────────────────┘
Added 3 labels, created 3 nodes, set 3 properties, created 1 relationship, started streaming 1 records in less than 1 ms and completed after 1 ms.
```

My problem is that nothing is returned unless I have at least one of these "special" nodes that is caught by the filter. The problem can be simulated by changing the input numbers to `[1, 2, 3]` which returns an empty result (no nodes) even though the nodes are created (as they should):

```
<empty result>
Added 3 labels, created 3 nodes, set 3 properties, completed after 2 ms.
```

I might be approaching the problem totally wrong but I've exhausted my Google skills... what Neo4J Cypher magic am I missing?

Comment: @jose_bacoy I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation about [Conditional Cypher Execution - Using correlated subqueries in 4.1+](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/conditional-cypher-execution/#_using_correlated_subqueries_in_4_1) describes how to solve this without the need for Apoc:

```
WITH [2, 3, 4] AS numbers
UNWIND numbers AS num
CREATE(n:Number {number: num})
WITH n
CALL {
    WITH n
    WITH n WHERE n.number > 3
    CREATE (n)-[:IM_SPECIAL]->(n)
    RETURN count(n)
}
RETURN collect(n) AS nodes
```

Thanks to Sanjay Singh and Jose Bacoy for putting me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

> WITH nodes, n WHERE n.number > 3

Each clause of a Cypher query must yield a result for for the subsequent lines of the query to consume. The above line yields nothing if you start with [1,2,3].

For your purpose, this will work.

```
WITH [1,2,3,4] as numbers
UNWIND numbers AS num
CREATE(n:Number {number: num})
WITH n
CALL apoc.do.when(n.number>3,
  'CREATE (n)-[:IM_SPECIAL]->(n) RETURN n',
   'RETURN n',
  {n:n}
)
YIELD value as m
WITH collect(m) AS nodes

RETURN nodes
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problem exists before reaching CREATE. I've seen Apoc mentioned a few times in similar context, but it isn't available to me at the moment, and to be honest I had preferred a solution without.